# React native passing response from request

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a main class

`class test extends Component`

and I created a component to render a login page

`var PageLogin = React.createClass({`

So in the `render` method of `test` I can just do

```
return (
  <View>
    <PageLogin></PageLogin>
  </View>
)
```

This login class uses a form which triggers the `login` method of the `PageLogin` component. The `login` method uses a simple `fetch` to post the data to a server.

```
login: function (values) {
  AsyncStorage.getItem('@test:app_access_token', (error, token) => {
    fetch(Config.BASE_URI + Config.LOGIN_URI, {//omitted})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
        return responseData;
    })
    .done();
  });
},
```

So from the form submit button I do

`var response = this.login(values);`
but when I debug `response` it is `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your login request trigger async request so you can not handle the response with `var response = this.login(values);`

try to change your code to:

```
login: function (values) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('@test:app_access_token', (error, token) => {
    fetch(Config.BASE_URI + Config.LOGIN_URI, {//omitted})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
        resolve(responseData);
      });
    });
  });
},

this.login(values).then((res)=>{
  var response = res;
});
```

Comment: I changed it to what you suggest but the response is still null

Comment: r u sure your API response has data?

Comment: I'm sure, I added a console log where I return `responseData` and where I reference it `response = res`. The first output was from the latter with `null` and the second output was from the `fetch` method with the actual response there.

Comment: same issue after removing that

Comment: i edited my answer to use Promise, is the issue still there?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help